# Getting ENOENT error using node.js and MySQL

Tags: node.js

I am following the node tutorial on  https://dev.to/achowba/build-a-simple-app-using-node-js-and-mysql-19me , to build a node application with Mysql. I'm getting the error `"ENOENT path: public/assets/img/image name"` which I have been able to trace to the line `uploadedFile.mv('public/assets/img/${image_name}', (err ) => {` in the file `player.js`.
I have tried `fs.writeFile` and `fs.copyFile` to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

**PLAYER.JS**

```
const fs = require('fs');

  module.exports = {
    addPlayerPage: (req, res) => {
      res.render('add-player.ejs', {
         title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
         ,message: ''
       });
   },
   addPlayer: (req, res) => {
      if (!req.files) {
          return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
       }


      let message = '';
      let first_name = req.body.first_name;
      let last_name = req.body.last_name;
      let position = req.body.position;
      let number = req.body.number;
      let username = req.body.username;
      let uploadedFile = req.files.image;
      let image_name = uploadedFile.name;
      let fileExtension = uploadedFile.mimetype.split('/')[1];
      image_name = username + '.' + fileExtension;

      let usernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE user_name = '" + username + "'";

      db.query(usernameQuery, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
              return res.status(500).send(err);
          }
          if (result.length > 0) {
              message = 'Username already exists';
              res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                  message,
                  title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
              });
           } else {
                if (uploadedFile.mimetype === 'image/png' || uploadedFile.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || uploadedFile.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
                uploadedFile.mv(`public/assets/img/${image_name}`, (err ) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    // send the player's details to the database
                    let query = "INSERT INTO `players` (first_name, last_name, position, number, image, user_name) VALUES ('" +
                        first_name + "', '" + last_name + "', '" + position + "', '" + number + "', '" + image_name + "', '" + username + "')";
                    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send(err);
                        }
                        res.redirect('/');
                    });
                        res.redirect('/');
                    });
                });
            } else {
                message = "Invalid File format. Only 'gif', 'jpeg' and 'png' images are allowed.";
                res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                    message,
                    title: "Welcome to Socka | Add a new player"
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you checked if the folder public/assets/img/ exists under htdocs and that you have writing privileges?

Comment: unfortunately no, neither do I seem to have a lampp folder.

Comment: at the start of the tutorial is a a section **folder structure** this you will have to build under your projects name. And i mean completely